# Tipo de kernel do Android

Tags: android, sistema-operacional, kernel

O sistema operacional Android desenvolvido pela Google é um kernel monolítico ou um microkernel?

Comment: Não é o kernel Linux? Este é monolítico, embora tenha algumas características de micro serviços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android usa o kernel linux (mas tem sua propria branch), e o linux kernel 'e monolítico.

Exemplo da estrutra Android:
[image: Exemplo da estrutra Android]

E um comparativo de tipos de kernel:
[image: Comparativo]